# Define type for object parameter that can have different structure

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an object as its argument, but the objects passed can have different structures. How can I define a type/types for the argument, without having to set any of the object properties as optional (since this does the whole typing thing a lot less useful)?

What I would like to do, but apparently doesn't work, is something like this:

```js
type One = {
  a: string
  b: string
}

type Two = {
  c: string
  d: string
}

type Three = {
  e: string
}

type OneOfTheseTypes = One | Two | Three

const myGenericFunction = (obj: OneOfTheseTypes) => {...}
```

P.S. I'm just starting to take my first baby steps with TypeScript so please forgive me if I'm thinking about this all wrong!

EDIT: So the function returns an object of the same type as the argument, and when I use the returned object (like `returnedObj.a`) I get errors saying "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'OneOfTheseTypes'." and "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Two'." I'm using TypeScript with React, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? It works exactly like you described you want it to.

Comment: @ritaj The function returns an object of the same type as the argument, and when I use the returned object (in this way: `returnedObj.a`) I get errors saying "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'OneOfTheseTypes'." and "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Two'." But maybe the problem isn't with the types declaration then? I'm using TypeScript with React I might add, I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Ellen Go through the concepts of Type Guards and Discriminated Unions. I hope they will be helpful in solving your problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TypeScript has correct error message that 'a' property does not exist on `OneOfTheseTypes`. But you can type cast your result to a narrow type with `as` operator if you sure about this.

Be careful though: you'll have a runtime error if your result will have type `Two` or `Three`.

```
let one: One = {
    a: 'hi',
    b: 'bye'
}

let res = myGenericFunction(one);
(res as One).a; // OK
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a terrible answer. Might as well said "just don't use Typescript".

Answer (score 0):

Example in your question is work and there is no errors of compilation in your example. You can easily solve your problem using `generics` directly:

```js
type One = {
  a: string
  b: string
}

type Two = {
  c: string
  d: string
}

type Three = {
  e: string
}

const myGenericFunction = <T>(obj: T): T => obj;

const testObject: One = {
  a: 'fieldA',
  b: 'FieldB'
};

myGenericFunction<One>(testObject);
```

[More information about generics.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics)

Comment: The function returns an object of the same type as the argument, and when I use the returned object (in this way: returnedObj.a) I get errors saying "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'OneOfTheseTypes'." and "Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Two'." But maybe the problem isn't with the way the types are defined then.